# SQL: return group of rows where condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My dataset looks like this:

```
PNR    Action Code
-----+-------------
1    |  Book
1    |  Exchange
1    |  Cancel
2    |  Book
2    |  Exchange
3    |  Book
4    |  Book
4    |  Cancel
```

I am trying to return all the rows for PNRs where Action code was "Cancel". So in this case, all the rows for PNRs 1 & 4.

I tried to use a Where Clause but that won't be correct as it would return only the rows WHERE action code was "Cancel". My result should look like:

```
PNR    Action Code
-----+-------------
1    |  Book
1    |  Exchange
1    |  Cancel
4    |  Book
4    |  Cancel
```

Comment: What is the query you tried to run?  You can edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps get the PNRs that you want from a select statement in your Where clause?

```
Select T1.PNR
      ,T1.[Action Code]
From myTable T1
Where T1.PNR in (
       Select PNR
       from myTable
       where [Action Code] = 'Cancel'
       )
```

Comment: Yes!! This works. Thanks a lot :) you made it sound really simple.

Comment: @biviz, glad to have helped.  I think that clarity and simplicity are often important concerns in creating a query

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do a self INNER JOIN in your table.
Something like that:

```
select      b.*
from        yourtable a
inner join  yourtable b
on          a.PNR = b.PNR
where       a.Action_Code = 'Cancel'
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i get your answer but i think this should help you

```
select * 
from your_table 
where PNR in (select PNR 
              from your_table 
              where Action_Code like 'Cancel')
```

Comment: This would work, but there is no need to use `LIKE` here. Instead, use `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, SmCnt = Sum(case when [Action Code] = 'Cancel' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by pnr) 
    from #pnrdata
) a where a.SmCnt > 0
```

Output as below:

```
+-----+-------------+
| PNR | Action Code |
+-----+-------------+
|   1 | Book        |
|   1 | Exchange    |
|   1 | Cancel      |
|   4 | Book        |
|   4 | Cancel      |
+-----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the CTE route here as well.

```
; with cte as (
    select 
    pnr
    ,[action code]
    ,SUM(case
        when [action code] = 'cancel' then 1
        else 0
    end ) OVER(partition by pnr order by pnr) as canceledItem
from test
)
select *
from cte
where canceledItem = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this, using a CTE to make it easily readable:

```
WITH RelevantPNRs AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT PNR
    FROM [YourTable]
    WHERE [ActionCode] = 'Cancel'
)
SELECT t.*
FROM [YourTable] t
    INNER JOIN RelevantPNRs r ON t.PNR = r.PNR
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from your_table 
where PNR=1 or PNR=4
```

Comment: This would work to display the results he wants, but only because you know 1 or 4 has 'Cancel'. This would not work dynamically filtering through a table if you are trying to pick out all PNR's that have 'Cancel' in Action Code.

Comment: Also, it's important to provide a brief explanation as to why this resolves the OPs isssue.